# not sure why i am getting an error for my instance

Tags: java

I have created two classes,  `PassCar` and `Motor`. My project requires that I create a `Motor` instance for each `PassCar`, but I am struggling to do so. When I try to create an instance of `Motor` in `PassCar`, it does not work.

I've attempted
`Motor motor = new Motor();`
and 
`private Motor motor = new Motor();`

Below is my code for `PassCar`
The error states that the constructor `Motor` is undefined.

```
public class PassCar extends Vehicle{

    private Motor motor = new Motor();// the error 
    private int numPass;
    private boolean AC;

    public PassCar(String make, String model, int year, double price, int numPass, boolean aC, Motor motor) {
        super(make, model, year, price);
        this.numPass = numPass;
        AC = aC;
        this.motor = motor;

    }


    public int getNumPass() {
        return numPass;
    }

    public void setNumPass(int numPass) {
        this.numPass = numPass;
    }

    public boolean isAC() {
        return AC;
    }

    public void setAC(boolean aC) {
        AC = aC;
    }

    public Motor getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }

    public void setMotor(Motor motor) {
        this.motor = motor;
    }


    public void description() {
        System.out.print("In this application, a passenger car is an every day vehicle registered to an individual");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s  = super.toString();
        s += "PassCar numPass = " + numPass + ", AC = " + AC + ", motor = " + motor;
        return s;
    }



}
```

code for Motor class

```
public class Motor {

    private String name;
    private int cylinders;
    private int bhp;
    private double displacement;

    public Motor(String name, int cylinders, int bhp, double displacement) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.cylinders = cylinders;
        this.bhp = bhp;
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }





    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCylinders() {
        return cylinders;
    }

    public void setCylinders(int cylinders) {
        this.cylinders = cylinders;
    }

    public int getBhp() {
        return bhp;
    }

    public void setBhp(int bhp) {
        this.bhp = bhp;
    }

    public double getDisplacement() {
        return displacement;
    }

    public void setDisplacement(double displacement) {
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Motor name = " + name + ", cylinders = " + cylinders + ", bhp = " + bhp + ", displacement = " + displacement;
    }

}
```

code to print information entered

public class VehicleTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PassCar p1 = new PassCar("Ford", "Mustang", 2016, 44500.0, 5, true, "EcoBoost", 6, 310, 2.3);
    System.out.print(p1);
}
```

}

Comment: Uh, where is the class `Motor` defined?

Comment: just posted my motor class, it's defined in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here

```
public Motor(String name, int cylinders, int bhp, double displacement) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.cylinders = cylinders;
    this.bhp = bhp;
    this.displacement = displacement;
}
```

You've created a constructor that takes some argument but you're trying to call the constructor with no arguments here

```
private Motor motor = new Motor();  //cant find constructor that takes no arguments
```

To fix the issue you have to declare a constructor with no arguments along with your other one.

```
public Motor(){
 //code here
}
```

Comment: that fixed my error thank you but gave me another one right after maybe you can help me out i'm trying to print out the information of a car i entered but it's giving me an error now saying my PassCar constructor is undefined

Comment: @anon What error?

Comment: i'll edit my post and add the code

Comment: just posted it the code

Comment: @anon it's the same issue. You've defined a constructor that accepts some specific arguments. Call the cosntructor with those arguments! `PassCar p1 = new PassCar("Ford", "Mustang", 2016, 44500.0, 5, true, new Motor("EcoBoost", 6, 310, 2.3));`

Comment: @anon if the answer solved your question consider accepting it using the big checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code in the Motor classs

public Motor(){
}

Comment: i just posted my motor class. i already had public motor(){} in there

Comment: you have the constructor with parameters. you need to add the empty constructor

Answer (score 0):

Add the empty parameter constructor to your Motor class. Like this;

```
public Motor() {
}
```